# Inheriting and good practices

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have few classes

```
class A;
class B;
class C;
class D;
```

Classes B,C,D inherits from A. In my problem i have multiple classes B,C,D and each of them have a static field for example

```
static int gold;
```

Class A is abstract class and it have method getGold();

Of course every class B,C,D has its own static field

```
static int gold;
```

and in every class (B,C,D) i implement in the same way

```
getGold()
{
    return gold;
}
```

It's copy & paste but i don't have idea how make it better.

B,C,D for example

- B is treusure box
- C is axe
- D is sword

Every object of the same class costs the same so this is why i want to have only one int Of course this is only example instead int i can have there for example class Gold instance :)

Comment: Personally, I would just make an abstract `getGold` function in the abstract base class and override it in each derived class to return a constant value. That means you need a class instance to get the value though.

Comment: what's the base class for a treasure box, axe or sword?

Comment: item ^^ i don't know this is a example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does not need to vary, use an enum for the value.

Regardless, return gold is not a bad idea.  If it was more complex, you might use the CRTP.  A helper template the inherits from A and implements get gold.

You pass B in as a template parameter and then inherit B from it.  The methods of the template can static cast this to a B and use B's state.

CRTP is pretty easy to Google.

Remember, return gold is probably best.